# Hibernate connection pool not working

Tags: java, hibernate, api, jsp

I created one api using jsp and hibernate. I used this option of hibernate -

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">50</property>
```

What I want is If I am getting 1000 hit concurrently on api then it should use only 50 connection not more than that. I thought above option of hibernate will help me to achieve this. But I tested my api on 10000 hit and I checked the open connection. It was around 3000. It means pool of connection not working.
How to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Hibernate documentation:

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability. Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property
>   with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool. For example, you might like to use c3p0.

Like mentioned, c3p0 is a good option.

Comment: It is looking good. I turned off Hibernate internal pool and trying to configure c3p0 with hibernate. I have Hibernate 4.x - c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar  , I think it should be enough. But I am getting this error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.pooledDataSource(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/sql/DataSource;

Comment: I'm using c3p0-0.9.5 and the pooledDataSource method is there. Here is how it should look like:

`public static DataSource pooledDataSource( DataSource unpooledDataSource, Map overrideProps )`

Could you try and download a newer version? I'm not sure that will solve the issue, but give it a try. If it doesn't, can you please add more details on where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: Anyhow I configured this in hibernate.cfg.xml But connections are still crossing pool limit. Now what should I do ?

Comment: @HimanshuMatta How did you fix the NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.pooledDataSource(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;Ljava/uti‌​l/Map;)Ljavax/sql/DataSource exception?